# Is it possible to use target column value on insert in SQL Server merge 'not matched' block?

Tags: sql-server-2017, merge

When working with a `MERGE` statement in SQL Server to use the updated state of a temp table to later modify records across multiple tables in a db schema, I am running in an issue when executing the following stored procedure:

```
-- Create procedure, set up, etc...

MERGE #TempTargetTable AS target
USING #TempSourceTable AS source
ON target.ExternalId = source.ExternalId
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET target.Price = source.Price,
    Action = 'update'

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY target THEN
    INSERT (InternalId, ExternalId, Price, Action)
    -- at runtime, target.InternalId is a non bindable multi part identifier when referenced here
    VALUES (target.InternalId, source.ExternalId, source.Price, 'create')

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY source THEN
     UPDATE SET Action = 'delete'
```

The procedure throws the classic exception - `multi part identifier 'target.InternalId' could not be bound`. I am aware of what this error means, but as one who is not intimately familiar with the internals of a merge statement, why is the `target` not accessible here? Is it possible to use `target` in this way?

Comment: Your title indicates 'matched' block, but I would think the actual problem would be in the 'not matched' blocked where you're referencing the `target.InternalId` in the `values` clause.  I could probably understand why that would be a binding problem since there was no match against the target table.

Comment: @ScottHodgin - thanks - i have updated the question to be more specific to the problem here - but regarding your second point, i was thinking something similar except isn't the target table implicitly available, as that is what the insert statement would write to in this context?

Comment: My understanding is - there is not match between the target and the source, so I cannot imagine being able to reference any data from the target since there was no match - in this situation, what would you think the value of target.InternalId be?  I'm not a merge expert either, just taking some guesses.

Comment: @ScottHodgin - :face_palm: - this question is a symptom of looking at this issue for a little too long in the context of a healthy dose of overtime - taking this comment i have implemented an alternative solution when resolving this value later on the proc. much thanks

Comment: <grin> - been there...